# Load Jquery BlockUI from text link

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

Not sure if this is possible, couldn't find a good answer...  I want a html link to launch a BlockUI "loading" box.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.blockUI.js"></script>

<SCRIPT language=JavaScript>
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#pop').click(function() { 
        $.blockUI({ 
            message: '<h1>Processing Query....</h1>', 
            timeout: 100000 
        }); 
    }); 
});</script>

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><div id=\"pop\"><a href=report$radio.php?prov=$prov&date1=$date1&starthour=$hour1&endhour=$hour2&date2=$date2&lookup=" . $row[$radio] . ">" . $row[$radio] . "</a></div></td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['count'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: Don't you need to bind the click event to the link now the div?

Comment: I figured it out, don't need the div...

    `<SCRIPT language=JavaScript>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('a').click(function() { 
            $.blockUI({ 
                message: '<h1>Processing Query....</h1>', 
                timeout: 10000 
            }); 
        }); 
    });</script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript>
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('a').click(function() { 
        $.blockUI({ 
            message: '<h1>Processing Query....</h1>', 
            timeout: 100000 
        }); 
    }); 
});</script>
```